# Label text not updating when RadGrid is refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, telerik, telerik-grid

I currently have a webpage with a Telerik RadGrid and a label which tells the last time that the RadGrid was refreshed. The RadGrid has a refresh command item, and the problem is that pressing the refresh button refreshes the RadGrid but does not update the label. In the RadGrid's PreRender event I have included the following code:

```
RefreshLabel.Text = "Last Refreshed: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

The text of the label changes when I manually refresh the page with the browser, but not when I press the RadGrid's refresh button. Is there some quirk to RadGrid's which would prevent the text of the label from changing? Or is there some other event that I should put this code in? I have tried putting the same code in the RadGrid's NeedDataSource event as well, to no avail.

I have gone through the debugger and it appears that the value of the label's text does indeed change when this line is executed, but the changes are not rendered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue was due to an AJAX error made on my part. I had not properly configured AJAX to work between the grid and the label. I resolved this by adding the following code within the RadAjaxManager:

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid">
     <UpdatedControls>
         <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RefreshLabel"/>
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```